Trouble sending two bytes from a pi 5 master to a slave arduino mega (using smbus2 library)
I've tried using the write_byte function in the smbus2 library and I've been successful using that from the Raspberry Pi 5 to turn an LED connected to the Arduino Mega on and off.
My project involves a 3 RPS Parallel Axis Manipulator with 3 steppers controlling it, and I'm doing data acquisition with computer vision through the Pi 5, calculating the necessary speed, steps and acceleration I want each of the manipulator's motors to go at. For the current test, I'm only sending one sample set of values of steps, speeds, and accelerations for each of the 3 motors. Since the value of the step/speed/accel can be higher than 255, I gather that I need to send two bytes to the Arduino instead of one for each value sent over i2c, and have to use the write_i2c_block_data function. Since I also can't really debug the arduino code using the serial monitor considering it's directly connected to the Pi 5 via its USB cable, I tried turning an LED on in different parts of the program and found that it doesn't go into the "receiveEvent" function as shown in the code below.
What could be the issue here? I'm not receiving any errors on the Pi 5 side, the motors home when I run the code (which is the initialization part of the arduino code), but the motors don't move at all in response to the i2c data that's been sent to them.
Python code on RPi 5:
from smbus2 import SMBus
from time import sleep
import struct

addr = 0x8 # bus address
bus = SMBus(1) # indicates /dev/i2c-1

steps = [600, 600, 600]
speeds = [500, 500, 500]
accels = [200, 200, 200]
ByteSteps = [0,0,0]
ByteSpeeds = [0,0,0]
ByteAccels = [0,0,0]

for i in range(0,3):
    ByteSteps[i] = list(struct.pack('>h', steps[i]))
    ByteSpeeds[i] = list(struct.pack('>h', speeds[i]))
    ByteAccels[i] = list(struct.pack('>h', accels[i]))

while True:
    for i in range (0,3):
        bus.write_i2c_block_data(addr, 0, ByteSteps[i])
        sleep(0.001)
        bus.write_i2c_block_data(addr, 0, ByteSpeeds[i])
        sleep(0.001)
        bus.write_i2c_block_data(addr, 0, ByteAccels[i])
        sleep(0.001)
    sleep(2)

Here's the Arduino code:
#include <Wire.h>
#include <AccelStepper.h>
#include <cvzone.h>

// Define motors config
const int MAX_STEPPERS = 3;
const int STEP_PINS[MAX_STEPPERS] = {3, 6, 9};   // Step pins for motors 1, 2, 3
const int DIR_PINS[MAX_STEPPERS] = {2, 5, 8};    // Direction pins for motors 1, 2, 3

// Create instances of AccelStepper for each motor
AccelStepper steppers[MAX_STEPPERS] = {
  AccelStepper(AccelStepper::DRIVER, STEP_PINS[0], DIR_PINS[0]),
  AccelStepper(AccelStepper::DRIVER, STEP_PINS[1], DIR_PINS[1]),
  AccelStepper(AccelStepper::DRIVER, STEP_PINS[2], DIR_PINS[2])
};

// Array to store received parameters for each motor
volatile long receivedSteps[MAX_STEPPERS] = {1, 0, 0}; // Initialize with 0 steps
volatile long receivedSpeed[MAX_STEPPERS] = {1, 0, 0}; // Initialize with 0 speed
volatile long receivedAcceleration[MAX_STEPPERS] = {1, 0, 0}; // Initialize with 0 acceleration

// Variables for managing serial input and commands
volatile bool runAllowed = false;

// The received integer
volatile int receivedValue = 0;

const int ledPin = 13; 

void setup() {
  // Initialize I2C communication as slave
  Wire.begin(0x8); // Address of the Arduino

  // Setup pin 13 as output and turn LED off at the beginning
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);

  // Set maximum speed and acceleration for each stepper motor
  for (int i = 0; i < MAX_STEPPERS; i++) {
    steppers[i].setMaxSpeed(100000); // Speed = Steps / second
    steppers[i].setAcceleration(800); // Acceleration = Steps /(second)^2
    steppers[i].disableOutputs(); // Disable outputs initially
    steppers[i].setCurrentPosition(0); // Reset current position to 0
  }
  home();
  // Register function to run when data is received
  Wire.onReceive(receiveEvent);
}

void loop() {
  if (runAllowed) {
    runMotors();
  }
  delay(100);
}

// Function to parse integer from I2C data
int parse_Integer() {
  if (Wire.available() >= 2) { // We expect 2 bytes for the integer
    byte byte1 = Wire.read();
    byte byte2 = Wire.read();
    
    // Combine the two bytes to form the integer
    receivedValue = (byte1 << 8) | byte2;
    return receivedValue;
  }
  return 0;
}

// Function to run when data is received
void receiveEvent(int howMany) {
  digitalWrite(ledPin, '1');
  for (int i = 0; i < MAX_STEPPERS; i++) {
      receivedSteps[i] = parse_Integer();
      receivedSpeed[i] = parse_Integer();
      receivedAcceleration[i] = parse_Integer();
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < MAX_STEPPERS; i++) {
    steppers[i].setAcceleration(receivedAcceleration[i]);
    steppers[i].setMaxSpeed(receivedSpeed[i]);
    steppers[i].move(receivedSteps[i]);
  }
  runAllowed = true;
}

void home() {
  runAllowed = true;
  for (int i = 0; i < MAX_STEPPERS; i++) {
    receivedSteps[i] = 200;
    receivedSpeed[i] = 800;
    receivedAcceleration[i] = 100;
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < MAX_STEPPERS; i++) {
    steppers[i].setAcceleration(receivedAcceleration[i]);
    steppers[i].setMaxSpeed(receivedSpeed[i]);
    steppers[i].move(-1 * receivedSteps[i]);
  }
  runMotors();
  for (int i = 0; i < MAX_STEPPERS; i++) {
    steppers[i].setCurrentPosition(0);
  }
  runAllowed = false;
}

void runMotors() {
  if (runAllowed) {
    while (steppers[0].currentPosition() != -1*receivedSteps[0] && steppers[1].currentPosition() != -1*receivedSteps[1] && steppers[2].currentPosition() != -1*receivedSteps[2]) {
      for (int i = 0; i < MAX_STEPPERS; i++) {
        steppers[i].enableOutputs(); // Enable outputs for all motors
        steppers[i].run(); // Step each motor
      }
      // if (Serial.available() > 0) return;
    }
    runAllowed = false;
  }
  if (!runAllowed) {
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_STEPPERS; i++) {
      steppers[i].disableOutputs(); // Disable outputs for all motors
    }
  }
}


Organizing your data into a struct and then having all the values for a sensor as a byte array to send in one packet seems like it would be helpful in your scenario.
This is useful when you want to concatenate several variables into a single byte array to send over Bluetooth, i2c, lora or any other protocol that works with arrays.
In other words you have a fixed byte array, and you squeeze in variables of different (or the same) data types and lengths into it, while still using it as a byte array afterwards.
A union in the Arduino example below is: the union is a fixed region of memory that we can write to in one format (as a structure) and then read from in another format (a byte array).
You can do it in reverse as well, write to it as a byte array, and read it as a structure.
Example of how to pack the bytes in Python:
import struct

step = [600, 600, 600]
speed = [500, 500, 500]
accel = [200, 200, 200]
sensor_count = 3

for sensor_id in range(sensor_count):
    bytes_to_send = struct.pack('<hhhh',
                                sensor_id,
                                step[sensor_id],
                                speed[sensor_id],
                                accel[sensor_id])
    print("send packed bytes of", bytes_to_send.hex('_', 2))
    # bus.write_i2c_block_data(addr, 0, bytes_to_send)



Gives the following output:
send packed bytes of 0000_5802_f401_c800
send packed bytes of 0100_5802_f401_c800
send packed bytes of 0200_5802_f401_c800

Example of how to unpack the bytes on the Arduino:
typedef struct sensorData_t{
  short sensorId;
  short step;
  short speed;
  short accel;
};

typedef union I2C_Packet_t{
  sensorData_t sensor;
  byte I2CPacket[sizeof(sensorData_t)];
};


const int PACKET_SIZE = sizeof(sensorData_t);
int test_data[PACKET_SIZE] = {0x01, 0x00, 0x58, 0x02, 0xf4, 0x01, 0xc8, 0x00};

I2C_Packet_t read_bytes;

I2C_Packet_t parse_packet() {
  // if (Wire.available() >= PACKET_SIZE) {
    for(int i=0; i < PACKET_SIZE; i++) {
      // read_bytes.I2CPacket[i] = Wire.read();
      read_bytes.I2CPacket[i] = test_data[i];
    }
    return read_bytes;
  // }
}

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  read_bytes = parse_packet();
  Serial.print(read_bytes.sensor.sensorId);
  Serial.print('-');
  Serial.print(read_bytes.sensor.step);
  Serial.print('-');
  Serial.print(read_bytes.sensor.speed);
  Serial.print('-');
  Serial.print(read_bytes.sensor.accel);
  Serial.println();
  delay(1000);
}

And give the following output in the serial monitor:
1-600-500-200
1-600-500-200
1-600-500-200
1-600-500-200


NOTE: I tested this without actually wiring up the i2c of the RPi and Arduino. Hopefully the commented out code shows what is needed if you did have the devices wired up correctly.

